# How to get Riot points for South American players in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

Which are the methods for paying in LoL, if I live in South America?

Comment: Is there something special for South America region? If not, maybe consider to make this question broader and ask for possibilities to get RP in general?

Comment: Is not that it is special, but I recently heard that the ways for paying and getting RP in South American Region is different as for USA

Comment: Wouldn't it be just easyer to check? I mean if your playing the game and you want some RP, just click the buy RP button and see what happens...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your options are:

- Credit card
- Paypal

Mobile payment and prepaid cards are only available in a few select countries. Paysafe cards are available in Argentina.

Answer (score 0):

According to this site about [Riot Points](http://www.free-riot-points.com/) they can be ordered via PayPal, credit card or a prepaid card.